# C# convert string Unicode to byte Ansi

Tags: c#, c, unicode, character-encoding

google didnt help me such as i wanted so im writing post here.
i have Unicode string in C# and C function (in dll) which want the char(ANSI)*.
i try to do

```
string tmp = "ala ma kota";
unsafe
{
    fixed (byte* data = &tmp.ToCharArray()[0])
    {
        some_function(data);
    }
}
```

but i cannot convert directly without encoding. I try to use Encode class but without any effects. I know that, the some_function needs to be called with char pointer. Where it points to array of byte.

Comment: _"I try to use Encode class but without any effects"_ - show that, because that's one main solution.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to do this explicitly yourself.

Instead, declare the C method using P/Invoke to accept a parameter of type `string`.

Then add to the P/Invoke declaration:

```
 [DllImport("YourDllName.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
```

The marshaller will then convert the string to ANSI for you.

Note that I'm assuming that the string is being passed TO the called function, so the parameter is NOT a pointer being used to return a new string FROM the called function.

See here for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.charset.aspx

In fact, the default is `CharSet.Ansi` so you might only need to declare the parameter as `string` instead of `byte*` (or whatever you are using just now).

Comment: Way better then my answer.

Comment: He might need a `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]` declared inline on the parameter since the default string marshaling is `UnmanagedType.BStr`.

Comment: @SynerCoder - you didn't have to delete, you had the other way to solve this.

Comment: @Matthew - that part about "output param" is confusing, I think you do mean "input param". Add a (mockup) function declaration to be clear.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Urk good point. I meant output from the point of view of the caller.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `System.Text` namespace:

```
string tmp = "ala ma kota";
unsafe
{
    fixed (byte* data = &System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(tmp)[0])
    {
        some_function(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: All strings in C# are UTF-16. Using the `Encode` class will get the bytes in a particular format.

Comment: Like @Romoku says, use the Target encoder. `ASCII.GetBytes()`